# Stationary distribution of an increasing stochastic process with a cut-off

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

I have a discrete time stochastic process $\{X_t : t \in T\}$ with continuous state space. Assume $X_0=0$ and increments $\delta_t$ are exponential with mean $\alpha$ (so its parameter is $\frac{1}{\alpha}$). Then the process is described by $X_t = X_{t-1} + \delta_t$. Whenever $X_t$ is larger than some threshold $\theta$ it is considered to be, but is not actually, set to $0$ again. So, assume that for some $t$, we have that $X_{t-1} < \theta$ and $X_t > \theta$, then $X_{t+1}$ has the same distribution as $ X_1 $.

If necessary, we can assume $\theta$ is relatively large in comparison with $\alpha$, say $\theta=100$ and $\alpha=0.5$.

**Example**

To illustrate the process, I give an example of a part of such a sequence.

$X_{200}=98.331$, $X_{201}=99.874$, $X_{202}=103.007$, $X_{203}=0.731$, $X_{204}=0.990$.

So, the increments are given by $\delta_{201} = 1.543$, $\delta_{202} = 3.133$, $\delta_{203}=0.731$ and $\delta_{204}= 0.259$.

That is, increment $\delta_{202}$ is large enough to make the value of $X$ larger than threshold $\theta$ (which was equal to $100$). Whenever this happens, we have one value of $X$ that is larger than $\theta$. This is $X_{202}$.

Then, $X$ is assumed to be $0$ again. This means that the next value of $X$ is equal to the next increment, which indeed is the case ($X_{203}=\delta_{203}$). Afterwards, the process continues as usual until it hits $\theta$ again.

**Question**

In the long run, what is the distribution of $X$? How do I show that it is distributed the way I think it is?

**Idea of the answer**

I suspect that $X$ is uniformly distributed between $0$ and $\theta$ (with probability mass $\frac{\theta}{\theta+\alpha}$) and that the remaining probability mass is exponentially distributed with mean $\alpha$ over the interval larger than $\theta$. That is,

\begin{align}
f(x;\theta,\alpha) &= \begin{cases} 
\frac{\theta}{\theta + \alpha} \frac{1}{\theta} & \text{ for } 0 \leq x \leq \theta \\
\frac{\alpha}{\theta + \alpha} \frac{1}{\alpha} e^{-\frac{x-\theta}{\alpha}} & \text{ for } x > \theta \\
0 & \text{ elsewhere }
\end{cases}
\end{align}

**Idea of proof**

However, I do not know how to prove this formally. It appears to me that the memoryless property of the exponential distribution plays a major role in the proof.

EDIT:

I consider using the following. I want to represent the distribution of one such iteration (so from $X_1$ until $X_t$ is greater than $\theta$ the first time). In this iteration we need an unknown amount of increments. The sum of $n$ increments is Erlang$\left(n,\frac{1}{\alpha}\right)$ distributed. However, we only have $n$ increments when after $n-1$ increments the total sum was less than $\theta$. Hence, I figured we could use conditioning and probably a truncated distribution.

I know that the mathematical notation is not right, but I hope the idea is clear.

\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \text{Erlang}\left(n,\frac{1}{\alpha}\right) | \left\{\text{Erlang}\left(n-1,\frac{1}{\alpha}\right) < \theta \right\} \cdot P \left[\text{Erlang}\left(n-1,\frac{1}{\alpha}\right) < \theta \right]
\end{align}

So, the idea is to sum all the Erlang distribution functions with shape parameters n=1 to infinity conditioned on the fact that the former increment did not make tot total sum larger than $\theta$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At stationarity, one asks that $$X\stackrel{\text{law}}{=}X\cdot\mathbf 1_{X<\theta}+\delta,$$ where the random variables $\delta$ and $X$ in the RHS are independent. Using the PDF $f$ and $g$ of $X$ and $\delta$, this translates as the condition that, for every $x>0$,
$$\ \qquad \qquad f(x)=P(X>\theta)\cdot g(x)+\int_0^{\min(\theta,x)} f(u)g(x-u)\mathrm du.\qquad\qquad (\ast)$$
When $g$ is the density of the exponential distribution $g(x)=be^{-bx}$ for some $b>0$, one can check that indeed $$f(x)=c$$ for every $x<\theta$ solves $(\ast)$ for some suitable $c$, namely, if, for every $x<\theta$, $$c=(1-c\theta)be^{-bx}+c(1-e^{-bx}),$$ that is, $$c=\frac{b}{1+b\theta}.$$ Finally, for every $x>\theta$, $(\ast)$ is solved by $$f(x)=(1-c\theta)be^{-bx}+ce^{-bx}(e^{b\theta}-1)=ce^{-b(x-\theta)}.$$
Note that $b=1/\alpha$ and that an easy consequence of all this is the value $$E(X)=\frac{\theta}2+\frac{2+b\theta}{2b(1+b\theta)}.$$